# Issue with node-fetch in Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

For some reason I keep getting this error when testing that fetch has been called and that it was called with a given URL.

The error message i'm getting is `received value must be a mock or spy function`.

Now when debugging I see that fetch is in fact a mockFunction. What am I missing?

```js
jest.mock('node-fetch', () => {
    const generateResponse = (value) => {
        return { json: () => ({ result: {pair: value}}) };
    };
    return jest.fn()
        .mockResolvedValue(generateResponse('EURUSD'))
});

const fetch = require('node-fetch')

it('should call service with valid url', async () => {
        const pair = '';

        await isValid(pair);

        expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(fetch.mock.calls[0][0]).toHaveBeenCalledWith(process.env.path + '/check');
```

Comment: It's not evident that the error refers to the test you posted and not another one. If this is so, please, provide a way to reproduce the problem, e.g. repl.it . From what you posted, it should be not possible to get this error.

Comment: Please provide the code of `isValid`